# How to print logs which have markers in them in logback using java

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I have a program in which I'm using slf4j with logback for logging and there is different type of logging pattern for clients and developers, like below:

```
if(userType.equals("clients")){
    encoder.setPattern("[%5level] - %date{dd MMM yyyy;HH:mm:ss.SSS} : %message%n");
}else{
    encoder.setPattern("[%5level] - %date{dd MMM yyyy;HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]: %message%n");
}
```

But I cannot apply the above code using configuration file because it won't give me the feasibility to do it.
Now I have applied markers in the logs and want to print only those logs which have marker in them. And for that I need to use configuration file.
Is there any way in which I can print the logs with markers without using the configuration file.

Comment: Not sure if it solves your problem, but the current code [has a big issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: I see another approach, to have two different log files, one for client and another one for developers. Adding to @f1sh comment, I suggest you to use camel case when naming variables to follow Java standard: `userType.equals("clients")`